# Neo4j and Cypher: Create relationships to nodes that have similar property keys

Tags: neo4j

Given the following nodes:

```
create(:ABC{id:'1', a:'axle',b:'bat'})
create(:ABC{id:'2', a:'ant',b:'ball',c:'clown'})
create(:ABC{id:'3', e:'elk',f:'fog',g:'gaff'})
create(:ABC{id:'4', a:'ax',c:'car',z:'zink'})
```

Using cypher, how would one create edges between nodes that share 1 or more property keys (regardless of their property value and with an unknown set of properties)?  I'm fairly certain I could iterate thru nodes individually via python and create edges, but I have tried without success to do this in cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that creates a `SHARES_KEYS_WITH` relationship between every pair of nodes that share at least one property with the same name (ignoring the `id` property, which all your example nodes have).

```
MATCH (m),(n)
WHERE (ID(m) > ID(n)) AND ANY (k IN KEYS(m) 
                              WHERE k <> 'id' AND k IN KEYS(n))
CREATE (m)-[:SHARES_KEYS_WITH]->(n)
RETURN m, n;
```

The `ID(m) > ID(n)` test ensures that we only evaluate each pair of distinct nodes just once. (Note that the `ID()` function returns the neo4j-generated internal identifier -- with is not the same as your `id` property.)

Comment: Thanks cybersam, that's exactly what I needed!  This helped me out a lot as I was digging around for hours for an answer.  I'm trying to extend this to also include the number of matched keys: MATCH (m),(n)
WHERE (ID(m) > ID(n)) AND ANY (k IN KEYS(m) 
                              WHERE k <> 'id' AND k IN KEYS(n))
CREATE (m)-[:SHARES_KEYS_WITH{match_count:count(KEYS(m))}]->(n)
RETURN m, n;

Comment: You can want to use either `LENGTH()` or `SIZE()` to get the length of a collection. `COUNT()` is only used to count result rows, and as an aggregation function can only be used in a `RETURN` or `WITH` clause. Also, you don't need to place a `match_count` property any way, since you can use a Cypher query to get the count; and I don't think your `match_count` would not give you a useful count.